# How to have dashed border in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, border, android-jetpack-compose

I can easily create a normal border using the `Modifier.border()` but how to create a dashed border as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some digging in the normal border modifier, I found out that it uses **Stroke** object which can take a parameter **PathEffect** that can make it dashed, here is a modified version of the normal border function that takes this parameter.
https://gist.github.com/DavidIbrahim/236dadbccd99c4fd328e53587df35a21

Comment: After the question above I started digging into this and was stuck at this error: "Type mismatch: inferred type is DashPathEffect but PathEffect was expected." This worked before alpha-09 but not on beta. After your answer I got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 63):

There isn't a parameter in `Modifier.border()` to achieve a dashed path.

However you can use a `DrawScope` to draw a dashed `Path` using [**`PathEffect.dashPathEffect`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/PathEffect#Companion.dashPathEffect(kotlin.FloatArray,%20kotlin.Float)).

Something like:

```
val stroke = Stroke(width = 2f,
    pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
)
```

You can draw it using the [**`drawBehind`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#drawbehind) modifier:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .size(250.dp,60.dp)
        .drawBehind {
            drawRoundRect(color = Color.Red, style = stroke)
        },
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(textAlign = TextAlign.Center,text = "Tap here to introduce yourseft")
}
```

[image]

If you want rounded corner just use the `cornerRadius` attribute in the `drawRoundRect` method:

```
drawRoundRect(color = Color.Red,style = stroke, cornerRadius = CornerRadius(8.dp.toPx()))
```

[image]

---

If you prefer you can build your custom `Modifier` with the same code above. Something like:

```
fun Modifier.dashedBorder(strokeWidth: Dp, color: Color, cornerRadiusDp: Dp) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val cornerRadiusPx = density.run { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

        this.then(
            Modifier.drawWithCache {
                onDrawBehind {
                    val stroke = Stroke(
                        width = strokeWidthPx,
                        pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
                    )

                    drawRoundRect(
                        color = color,
                        style = stroke,
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(cornerRadiusPx)
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

and then just apply it:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .size(250.dp,60.dp)
        .dashedBorder(1.dp, Red, 8.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = "Tap here to introduce yourself",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is no longer `Modifier.border()`?  Actually I am using android beta 04 and it's not deprecated

Comment: @DavidIbrahim The Modifier.border() exists and it is not deprecated.

Comment: Ohh sorry I misunderstood, I thought you are providing a different solution for this problem because of my code going deprecated lol.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti if I need add radius what I need to do?

Comment: @CôngHải check the updated answer. Just use the cornerRadius attribute in the drawRoundRect method.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote this extension for the Modifier you can simply use it or modify it.

```
fun Modifier.dashedBorder(width: Dp, radius: Dp, color: Color) = 
    drawBehind {
        drawIntoCanvas {
            val paint = Paint()
                .apply {
                    strokeWidth = width.toPx()
                    this.color = color
                    style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
                    pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
        }
        it.drawRoundRect(
            width.toPx(),
            width.toPx(),
            size.width - width.toPx(),
            size.height - width.toPx(),
            radius.toPx(),
            radius.toPx(),
            paint
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this as is my border had a bit of a gap from the actual edge of the view. 
Updating to this fixed that


    it.drawRoundRect(
                (width.toPx() / 2),
                (width.toPx() / 2),
                size.width - (width.toPx() / 2),
                size.height - (width.toPx() / 2),
                radius.toPx(),
                radius.toPx(),
                paint
            )

Answer (score 1):

```
@Composable
private fun AddNewFileButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val stroke = Stroke(
        width = 4f,
        pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
    )

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .drawBehind {
                drawRoundRect(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    style = stroke,
                    cornerRadius = CornerRadius(16.dp.toPx())
                )
            }
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .clickable { onClick() },
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Add new item"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]