# How to pause/resume a jetpack compose infinite transition animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, jetpack-compose-animation

For my android app i'm using a custom modifier which draws a dashed border as detailed in this [stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039676/12871582).

I now want to conditionally animate that dashed border: If the view is currently selected, then animate, else pause.

I managed to implement this behavior using an infinite transition.
However, there's some "jumping" motion when toggling `animate`, which i'd like to avoid, e.g. by just pausing the `infiniteTransition`. But how do i do this?

```
fun Modifier.dashedBorder(
    color: Color,
    strokeWidth: Dp,
    strokeLength: Dp,
    animate: Boolean = false,
) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val strokeLengthPx = density.run { strokeLength.toPx() }

        val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
        val offset by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = strokeLengthPx * 2,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(1000, easing = LinearEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
            )
        )

        this.then(
            Modifier.drawWithCache {
                onDrawBehind {
                    val stroke = Stroke(
                        width = strokeWidthPx,
                        pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                            intervals = floatArrayOf(strokeLengthPx, strokeLengthPx),
                            phase = if (animate) offset else 0f, // <-- cause of jumping motion
                        )
                    )

                    drawRect(
                        color = color,
                        style = stroke,
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will be helpful to you:

[image]

```
   fun Modifier.dashedBorder(
        color: Color,
        strokeWidth: Dp,
        strokeLength: Dp,
        animate: Boolean = true,
    ) = composed(
        factory = {
            val density = LocalDensity.current
            val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
            val strokeLengthPx = density.run { strokeLength.toPx() }
            // store the last animate value be next animate start
            var lastAnimValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            val anim = remember(animate) { Animatable(lastAnimValue) }

            LaunchedEffect(animate) {
                if (animate) {
                    anim.animateTo(
                        // Important !!! Animate Target need add the lastAnim value, Simple math knowledge :)
                        (strokeLengthPx * 2 + lastAnimValue), animationSpec =
                        infiniteRepeatable(
                            animation = tween(1000, easing = LinearEasing),
                            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
                        )
                    ) {
                        lastAnimValue = value // store the anim value
                    }
                }
            }

            this.then(
                Modifier.drawWithCache {
                    onDrawBehind {
                        val stroke = Stroke(
                            width = strokeWidthPx,
                            pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                                intervals = floatArrayOf(strokeLengthPx, strokeLengthPx),
                                phase = anim.value, // always use the anim
                            )
                        )
                        drawRect(
                            color = color,
                            style = stroke,
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
```